# Use a string as seed generator for random number generation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, random, uuid, random-seed

I have a `uuid` (e.g. `a3989f5a-1c4b-11e3-8573-0025906a9230`) which I need to use as a seed for random number generation in ruby on rails.

Every time a request comes with said `uuid`, I need to get the *same sequence of random numbers* generated. Is there any other such function that I am missing here?

Please note: it is very important that for a given `uuid`, the same sequence of random numbers need to be generated every time.

I have tried using the `Kernel.srand()` method provided by ruby, however this only accepts integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
srand "a3989f5a-1c4b-11e3-8573-0025906a9230".tr('-', '').to_i(16)
```

It will seed Ruby rng from UUID as hex number after we strip dashes

Comment: This is the correct answer. It works because a UUID is just a hex-encoded 128-bit number (the dashes are just for human readability). It's also worth noting that for OP's use case [`Random.new(seed)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Random.html#method-c-new) may be useful to initialize multiple RNGs rather than using `srand` to seed the global RNG.